# I cannot find $nvpHeader variable in PayPal NVP source code

Tags: php, paypal

I have downloaded [PayPal API: Name-Value Pair Interface](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks#NVP) for php, and I want to create paypal library for zend framework.

In source code I found `$nvpstr = $nvpHeader.$nvpstr;` in `ReviewOrder.php` file.

But I cant find/understand from where `$nvpHeader` variable comes.

AND

In `CallerService.php` in global scope there is `$nvp_Header`. For what this variable?
It does not used.